# Remove duplicate from two Array of Object using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two array variables

```
let itSchool = [
  {
    'school': 'HS-1',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'John'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Eddy'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'school': 'HS-2',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'Edward'
      },
      {
        'name': 'John'
      }
    ]
  }
]

let itAbsence = [
  {
    'school': 'HS-1',
    'teacher': 'John'
  },
  {
    'school': 'HS-2',
    'teacher': 'Edward'
  }
]
```

How to remove the same name of `itSchool` by compare with `itAbsence`? The result become:

```
itSchool = [
  {
    'school': 'HS-1',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'Eddy'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'school': 'HS-2',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'John'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: why is `teachers` (plural) in `itAbsence ` a string? what's the format here?

Comment: I haven't tried

Comment: @ramboeistblast then try! Everybody here will help you with concrete problems, but nobody wants to do your job.

Comment: I already edited it

Comment: i have tried like this

`
let newSchool = itSchool
itAbsence.map(rA => {
  itSchool.map(rS => {
    for (const [k, v] of rS.teachers.entries()) {
      if (v.name == rA.teacher) {
        rS.teachers.pop()
      }
    }
    return rS
  })
  newSchool = itSchool
})

console.log('newSchool = ', newSchool)
`

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Downvotes are not "1 per reason". (Besides, since they are anonymous, you can't even know if the downvotes are for the same reason.) Upvoting to counter downvotes [is highly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408).

Comment: @Ivar Cool, but people are not mentioning why it has been downvoted. I felt upvoting because new people doesn't may be able to know properly posting the question. And people doesn't give time to edit the question if they are missing something through comments. I can upvote and sit silently i felt telling and doing it. Because even i was also new to stackoverflow at a point. When you are a beginner you will learn lot. Still i am expecting that while atleast for downvoting they should tell the reason so we can improve :)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I used to comment on my votes, but unfortunately it happened too often that people who disagreed with it, revenge downvoted my posts out of spite. Besides that, [there are plenty of reasons why downvotes are not mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437). Also a post should be up to the sites standards as soon as you hit the submit button.There are plenty of resources to help users with that in the Help Center. And if users do edit their posts, the downvotes can be undone. Remember that first and foremost votes are a content rating system.

Comment: @Ivar Okay atleast you are able to understand.. Thanks for the info happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
itAbsent.forEach( absent => {
  let index = itSchool.findIndex( schoolVar => absent.school === schoolVar.school );
  if( index === -1 ) return;
  let teacherIndex = itSchool[index].teachers.findIndex( teacher => teacher.name === absent.teacher );
  if(teacherIndex != -1) itSchool[index].teachers.splice(teacherIndex, 1);
}
```

So, here's a basic logic:

1. iterate on `itAbsent`
2. for every object in it, find the index of the matching school in `itSchool`.
3. find the absent teacher's index in the `teachers` array of that school.
4. remove necessary teacher with `array.splice()`.

Note a few things:

1. this will work only if there is one absent teacher per school. If there are more- they'd have to be on different objects in the `itAbsent` array.
2. if a school or absent teacher are not found in `itSchool`, function will do nothing (just skips it).
3. the `splice` method literally changes the same array we're woking on, e.g `itSchool[index].teachers` in this case. If you don't want to change it you'll have to create a copy of it and pass that copy to this code to change.

Answer (score 2):

One line solution

```js
const itSchool = [
  {
    "school": "HS-1",
    "teachers": [
      {
        "name": "John"
      },
      {
        "name": "Eddy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "school": "HS-2",
    "teachers": [
      {
        "name": "Edward"
      },
      {
        "name": "John"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const itAbsence = [
  {
    "school": "HS-1",
    "teachers": "John"
  },
  {
    "school": "HS-2",
    "teachers": "Edward"
  }
]


const output = itSchool.map(s => ({...s, teachers: s.teachers.filter(ss => ss.name !== (itAbsence.find(i => i.school === s.school).teachers))  }))


console.log(output)
```

Comment: but it HS-2 school teachers is empty array, it must be John

`
[
  {
    'school': 'HS-1',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'Eddy'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'school': 'HS-2',
    'teachers': [
      {
        'name': 'John'
      }
    ]
  }
]
`

Comment: in the given question hs-2 teachers property is not an empty array. Kindly run the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it

```
let newSchool = itSchool
itAbsence.map(rA => {
  itSchool.map(rS => {
    for (const [k, v] of rS.teachers.entries()) {
      if (v.name == rA.teacher) {
        rS.teachers.shift()
      }
    }
    return rS
  })
  newSchool = itSchool
})

console.log('itSchool = ', itSchool)
```

Comment: the first time I used .shift ()